# Custom POST routes for create action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

### Explaining the context

"I am learning Rails, building asocial app f
"I think my problem with the routes...
"...still figuring them out.
" 3 days trying all sorts of things.
"This is where I am now, and something is not working as expected.
"Any help/pointers would be appreciated! :)

### The Problem

After sign in with devise i route to  the main page called '/opinions"
When I access the form to create a new forum and I hit submit, "
the form post to '/opinions' correctly "
but I am rendering the same form in my user page '/users/1"
When i hit submit there i git this error ."

```
## The log

Started POST "/users/2" for ::1 at 2020-10-22 00:05:18 +0300
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/2"):

## config/routes.rb


  resources :followers
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    root to: 'devise/sessions#new'

  end

  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :create]do
    resources :followers, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
  resources :opinions
  


## _form.html.erb

<%= form_with(model: @opinions, local: false) do |form| %>
  <div class="field rich p-3">
    <div class="control">
      <%= form.rich_text_area :body, label: "What's Your Opinion", input_html: {class: "textarea"}, wrapper: false, label_html: {class: "label"}, placeholders: "Your opinion...", autofocuse: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= form.button :submit, class: "button is-info" %>

<% end %>

## Rake Routes

            root GET    /                                                                                        devise/sessions#new
                       user_followers POST   /users/:user_id/followers(.:format)                                                      followers#create
                        user_follower DELETE /users/:user_id/followers/:id(.:format)                                                  followers#destroy
                                users GET    /users(.:format)                                                                         users#index
                                      POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         users#create
                                 user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#show
                             opinions GET    /opinions(.:format)                                                                      opinions#index
                                      POST   /opinions(.:format)                                                                      opinions#create
                          new_opinion GET    /opinions/new(.:format)                                                                  opinions#new
                         edit_opinion GET    /opinions/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             opinions#edit
                              opinion GET    /opinions/:id(.:format)                                                                  opinions#show
                                      PATCH  /opinions/:id(.:format)                                                                  opinions#update


## opinions_controller 

 
  def create
    @opinion = @user.opinions.build(opinion_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @opinion.save
        format.html { redirect_to opinions_url, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @opinion }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @opinion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

## users_controller

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include TheUser
  include ActionText::Attachable
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :user_signed_in?

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @mutual_friends = User.where(id: show_two_friends)

  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @opinion = @user.opinions

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user
        format.html
        format.js { @current_user = @user }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  
end
```

## What am I doing wrong please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error is dispatched because you should not make a POST to /resource/:id (/users/2). In case you expect to update info use PUT. I think that you are passing @opinions to form_with helper, which I guess is an array of Opinion of a user. If so, you should create a variable @opinion = Opinion.new to execute correctly in the user views. But please edit the post with the UserController.rb file to help you better.

A correct way should be like this:

```
##UserController.rb
...
def show ## I will guess that you are using Opinion form in User Show
  @user = User.find(:id)
  @opinions = @user.opinions
  @new_opinion = Opinion.new
end
...
## app/views/users/show.html.erb
...
<%= form_with(model: @new_opinion, local: false) do |form| %>
  <%= render 'opinions/form' form: form %>
<% end %>
...

## app/views/opinions/_form.html.erb
...
<div class="field rich p-3">
  <div class="control">
    <%= form.rich_text_area(
      :body, 
      label: "What's Your Opinion", 
      input_html: {class: "textarea"}, 
      wrapper: false, 
      label_html: {class: "label"}, 
      placeholders: "Your opinion...", 
      autofocuse: true 
    ) %>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
...
  <%= form.button :submit, class: "button is-info" %>
...
```

Remember, the form partial should not contain the form_with tag. Use local variables of render tag to pass the form attribute.

Hope I help. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been struggling more than to day's in this thing and I thought the problem with the routes, it worked like a charm. I add the user controller to the post. I still have one question how to redirect the opinion to the same user feed instead of redirect to the opinions page when i am in the user profile, not the home page "/opinions"

Comment: Well, you can add an extra param in the form to know where you are submitting the form. And in the OpinionController#create you can make a conditional where you determine depending on that param where to redirect the request. And put it in the view as a hidden field.